# MySql command not working due to ' being present

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

using mysql-connector I have tried executing this line

`"insert into line (Line_Name, Stops, Bus_Num) values ('Blue', '['Canada', 'US']', '['qwe123', 'qwr123']')"`

MySql seems to find a syntax error, but if I rather execute this

`"insert into line (Line_Name, Stops, Bus_Num) values ('Blue', '[Canada, US]', '[qwe123, qwr123]')"`

It works smooth, but sadly in python its impossible to remove the `'` from a string type variable. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: ```values ('Blue, '['Canada', 'US']'...``` isn't valid.You must escape the ```'``` inside the quotes. i.e. ```'[\'Canada\', \'US\']'```

Comment: Recommend not putting multiple values in any database column. Use a separate table. Only pain and suffering will result from the current structure.

Comment: Use a [prepared statement](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/#h-example-to-insert-data-into-mysql-table-using-parameterized-query). That takes care of escaping like for `'`. And is a security measure against **SQL injection**. Though @danblack might be right: it might be worth creating extra subtables.

Comment: That seemed to work @ewong thanks a lot

Comment: *I have tried executing this line* Do you want to say that you insert the values immediately into the SQL code? If so than you're wrong, use prepared statement with placeholders. When you provide the values for these placeholters the connector performs all needed transformations which eliminates this kind of problem (and a lot of another problems). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html